# How to stop an application from being launched in Android

Tags: android, service, background, restrict

I am running a background service that restricts users from launching applications, even when my application is not in the foreground. Is there any way to stop them from being able to launch certain applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launching of app is handled by the Launcher. This cannot be controlled from a third party app. Neither Android provides you the app lauch details like a broadcast.